# Qt vs. WPF - easier GUI creation

Tags: c++, .net, wpf, qt, user-interface

I want to create an Application which also needs a lot of GUI stuff. I started with WPF and immediately found its limits, for example with the tweaking of a DataGrid... (actually not a limit, but needs a lot of effort...)

The application will also include self-made diagrams like a Gantt-diagram (at least similar to a Gantt-diagram).

Now I've read a little bit about Qt and also made some simple forms. I also know that nearly everything is possible with Qt (like an interactive Gantt-diagram). But the main question is, which one is easier (less effort) for creating *non*-standard UI-elements. WPF or Qt?

Comment: try google if there is some ready solutions. For qt I found something like http://www.ics.com/products/qt/kd-chart/kd-gantt#.UqHGS41D9Yg There is a big chance that something similar is available for .net.